# How to search subdirectories for files and then copy them?

Tags: windows, batch, xcopy

When I use the findstr command, I can put /s and that will search all the subdirectories. With the copy command, is there such a thing as well? It only seems to copy files within a specific directory as opposed to searching for the file in all of the subdirectories, even when I put an asterisk between the file I need and the primary directory.

Comment: Copy does not have a S switch,  Xcopy does have a /S that acts similar to what you have asked for.

Comment: Does not that copy the folders themselves? I'd like files

Comment: it will copy both files and folders. Are you wanting to just copy files only.  Does your version of windows have robocopy? If so, it can copy just files and go through sub-folders.

Comment: Assuming just files, 1) use a "dir /ad /s /b >>Somefile.bat"  then go into the bat file with notepad or other tool of your preference and add  "copy " before each line and "\*.\* mydestination\\*.* " with whatever switches you want (How you handle the name conflict if the same file name is in 2 or more directories)

Comment: I'm looking for it to be automatic, not semi automatic, as in that the user has to edit something in order for it to work. It should basically look through every folder in the %userprofile% directory for a specific file and copy it. I'll try robocopy as you said and see if it works out

Comment: Yep robocopy with the /s switch also seems to copy folders and not only files... know of any way to make it only copy files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690245/robocopy-copy-folders-content-to-a-single-folder

Comment: can't make out too much from that link, not really a programmer, I only know the basics of batch. you said earlier, "Does your version of windows have robocopy? If so, it can copy just files and go through sub-folders." so is it really that simple, because I do have robocopy?